# Full nodes suddenly appearing and dissapearing in a geographic region

Tags: full-node, mining-profitability

Aside from changing [mining profitability](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/monero-mining-calculator), what are some reasons why large numbers of full nodes would suddenly appear (and later disappear) within a certain geographic region.

For example, what could have caused the number of [full nodes](https://monerohash.com/nodes-distribution.html) in China to jump from 8 to 38 over just a few days [last month](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4oqs8d/and_then_one_day_china_discovered_monero/) with fairly fast drop back down near prior levels (11 as of today) shortly afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a suspected bug in the P2P connectivity code, which causes some nodes to not see the entire Monero network, so the monerohash.com only sees part of the network. It is unknown how much of the network this "hides" from the statistics.

Comment: Since the quoted example mentioned China, is it possible the Great China Firewall causes those nodes to hide? If that is true is it likely there are more full node in China we do not know about?

Comment: It is possible, yes. However, there were reports of two nodes failing to see each other in the same geographical region, so if the GFC is a reason, it is not the only one.